# How to find specific value from index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say that `input(fag) == informasjonsvitenskap` like the value in `list(FagKode)`, if that is true i want it to print the values in karak that has element in relation to INFO, like INFO100,INFO132 and INFO233. And if `input(fag)` is økonomi i want it to print the values in karak the has the code ECON.

i am new to python and please tell me if i dont explain it well.

My next question will be that i only will print elemtents related to the exact value, like if `input(emnenivå) == 100`, only INFO100 AND INFO132 will print, and if `input(emnenivå) == 200` will only INFO233 be printed,

```
emner = ['INFO100','INFO132','INFO233']
FagKode = [['informasjonsvitenskap','INFO'],['økonomi','ECON']]
karak = [['INFO100','C'],['INFO132','B'],['INFO233','C'],['ECON218','A']]


def start():
    global meny
    global fag
    meny = int(input('Tast inn ønsket valg (press 0 for meny): '))

    if meny == 1:
      valg_fag = input('Press Enter for å velge fag/emner (Skriv "alle" for å vise alle fag/emner)\n: ')

    if meny == 1 and valg_fag == 'alle':
      for i in karak:
        print(*i)

    elif meny == 1 and valg_fag == '':
      fag = input('- Fag: ')
      emnenivå = int(input('- Nivå: '))
      try:
        if fag in FagKode[0] and emnenivå in range(1,1000):
          ???????
          ???????
        else:
          print('Du har gjort noe feil!')
      except ValueError:
          print('NEI')

start()
```

Thanks for help in advance  :)

Comment: For the first part, do you want to print the element started in `INFO` or the second element ?

Comment: i will try to explain, i am new to python. informasjonsvitenskap is related to INFO, and økonomi is related to ECON . if input(fag) = informasjonsvitenskap, and input(emnenivå) = 100, i want to print INFO in the range of 100,199. if input(emnenivå) = 200, then i want to print INFO in range of 200,299. and i want to print both of the elements, for example, a print value could be like INFO100, C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use list comprehension for this:

```
karak = [['INFO100','C'],['INFO132','B'],['INFO233','C'],['ECON218','A']]

info_items = [item for item in karak if item[0].startswith("INFO")]
econ_items = [item for item in karak if item[0].startswith("ECON")]

print(info_items)
print(econ_items)
```

Regarding second part: What supposed to be returned if emnenivå is smaller than 100? Do you have INFO items with two-digit numbers?

**EDIT:**
To match INFO with level 100 or 200 only you could use first digit from `emnenivå` as a distinguishing factor. And you get the first `emnenivå` digit by converting it to string and using index=0, like this: `str(emnenivå)[0]`. Sample code:

```
emnenivå = 123
print("\nExact match for emnenivå={}:".format(emnenivå))
info_items_exact = [item for item in karak if item[0].startswith("INFO{}".format(str(emnenivå)[0]))]
print(info_items_exact)
emnenivå = 200
print("\nExact match for emnenivå={}:".format(emnenivå))
info_items_exact = [item for item in karak if item[0].startswith("INFO{}".format(str(emnenivå)[0]))]
print(info_items_exact)
```

Comment: This looks great, but where do i put this in my code? if emnenivå is smaller than 100 it should print, that this level is not possible and should give me another try at input for fag end emnenivå.. Thank you rpiwko

Comment: info_items also print INFO233, it should only print INFO with level 100, like INFO100, INFO132. maybe its possible to use the range function?

Comment: I edited my initial reply with new list comprehension expression that should work for more precise selections.

Comment: This worked out perfectly, i am very greatful for this contribution. :)